# jprofilerti.dll in absolute path, with error: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

Tags: java, jboss6.x, jprofiler

I am using JProfiler6 with JBoss6 and JDK1.7. I am trying to bring up my JBoss but i am getting error at server startup:

*Error occurred during initialization of VM.

Could not find agent library C:\Install\jprofiler7\bin\windows\jprofilerti.dll in absolute path, with error: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform.*

Please help me to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the output of `java -version`?

Answer (score 2):

In your -agentpath VM parameter that loads the JProfiler agent, replace `C:\Install\jprofiler7\bin\windows\jprofilerti.dll` with `C:\Install\jprofiler7\bin\windows-x64\jprofilerti.dll`.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely using a 64-bit Java runtime environment. A 64-bit JRE cannot load 32-bit native libraries.

Either get a version of JProfiler6 that has 64-bit native libraries, or use a 32-bit JRE.